# How can touch off keyDown() or keyUp() in ClickListener (Libgdx)

Tags: libgdx

I write a demo to test button, but I have a little problem. the keyDown and keyUp was not work. the code like that.

I create a button join stage and add ClickListener to button, the listener is work,but can't touch off keyDown and keyUp method in ClickListener，Why and How to touch off it

ButtonScreen

```
public class ButtonScreen implements Screen {

    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    public Stage stage;

    public ButtonScreen() {
        
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        
        Viewport viewport = new ScreenViewport(camera);
        stage = new Stage(viewport);

        //add stage to Inputprocessor
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        //make button
        Button button = new Button(new TextureRegionDrawable(ImgConsUtil.timeFileAtlas.findRegion(CardConstant.DO)),
                new TextureRegionDrawable(ImgConsUtil.timeFileAtlas.findRegion(CardConstant.ONE_TIME)));
        button.setPosition(200,200);
        button.addListener(new MyButtonClickListener());

        //add button to stage
        stage.addActor(button);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        camera.update();
        PreparClass.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        
        stage.act();
        
        stage.draw();

    }
}
```

MyButtonClickListener

```
public class MyButtonClickListener extends ClickListener{

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown (InputEvent event, int keycode) {
       
        System.out.println("keyDown");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp (InputEvent event, int keycode) {
        
        System.out.println("keyUp");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("touchdown");
        return false;
    }

    public void clicked(InputEvent inputEvent, float x,float y){
        System.out.println("clicked");
    }
```

I press the key but woun‘t run to keyup or keydown

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason，The button does not get focus and does not respond to any events. It only gets focus when the mouse is clicked. In other words, Button only responds to click events. so，If you want to get keyboard events, just set a “Listener” to the “Stage”.